# populate html form using python and open in browser without submitting

Tags: python, html, forms

I am trying to write a python script that populates the fields of an html form and then opens that form in a browser WITHOUT submitting it.

I can fill the form and submit it using *URllib* and *urllib2* however I dont want to submit it - I want the person to check the data and then submit it manually.

I have seen this might be possible with Mechanize or Selenium but I want to try and do this with what comes standard (the script will be run on various computers by people who don't know what python is...)

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

Opens the form in the browser? This will be tricky, as there is no cross-platform way to open a browser and point it to a URL. On Linux you would probably use `xdg-open`, on Windows I believe you can just use `start`, and I have no clue on Mac OS X. But regardless, you would use the `subprocess` module to open a web browser.

As for the filling it out part...you might be able to replicate the page and serve the local, pre-filled copy with a basic webserver, shutting it down when the user submits the form. I don't think this would be the best idea.

An alternative is using [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) script to automate everything - open the user's web browser, populate the fields, maybe even move the mouse cursor to the submit button or highlight it without clicking. That sounds more like what you're trying to achieve.